# A function bounded on an interval

Tags: functions

If a function is affine and bounded on [0,1], does that mean: For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$? Or does it mean there exists $M,N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in [0,1]$, $N\leq f(x) \leq M$?

Comment: The second is the right one

Comment: :D thanks friend

Answer (score 0):

A function as bounded on an interval $I$ means that the funtion has a maximum value and a minimum value within that interval.

(In your statement, $[a,b]$ is a closed and bounded interval, so $f$ trivially has upper and lower bounds.)